# How much of the peach pit must be broken for successful germination?

Tags: seeds, planting, germination, peaches

I successfully removed 1/4 of the pit of a peach seed. About 1/2 a cm, what I was told is the root, grew out of it.

Is that 1/4 opening enough for the non-root part to grow out of it or should I take the risk of fully opening the pit?

In other words, can the non-root part grow out of the same 1/4 opening of the pit or can it only grow out of the other side, which is still covered by the very tough pit?

Answer (score 3):

None of the peach pit must be broken. Simply plant them in the fall, in the ground, and wait. Come spring, you will get some sprouts, and likely also some will fail to sprout, so plant more pits than you are trying to grow trees.

Evidently the odds of getting an acceptable/palatable peach from a seedling tree are a bit higher than for apples; in neither case will the seedling be the same as the parent.

Comment: thanks for the effort, but you did not answer my question, what you wrote can be read all over the web, what I am asking cannot be easily found

Comment: It is often difficult to find detailed answers to questions that are based on false premises. Since you don't need to break peach pits at all for them to germinate successfully, *how much do I need to break them* and *have I broken it enough* are pointless questions when the correct answer is "they don't need to be broken at all."